# Named Credential authentication with GoToWebinar (OAuth2)

Tags: apex, callout, oauth2, namedcredentials

I am trying to connect Salesforce with GoToWebinar (GTW) to automate webinar activities within my Salesforce app. I am attempting to use Named Credentials (OAuth2) to authenticate with GTW.

I have followed their documentation on how to [authorise users](https://developer.goto.com/guides/HowTos/03_HOW_accessToken/), and also found another posted on here in [another question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252277/named-credential-for-gotowebinar-app-oauth-v2-0) thats experienced issues.

Following both pages I created the following:

GTW OAuth Client

Auth Provider
[image]
(the callback URL is added in the GWT OAuth client settings)

Self Signed Cert

[image]

Named Credential

[image]

When I save the Named Credential it initiates the auth flow, but GTW returns an unexpected error, problem is because its all in the UI I can't really debug what the issue is.

I have also tried running the following anon apex to run a test endpoint request:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:GoToWebinar/G2W/rest/v2/organizers/(MYORGID)/webinars');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

This returns a 403 error in the response.

Can anyone help me debug this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to set up a named credential to GoToWebinar(trial version) on my developer org and also get a successful HTTP response (status code 200) for the anonymous apex code given in your question. As mentioned in the [other link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252277/named-credential-for-gotowebinar-app-oauth-v2-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) in your question, enabling '***Send client credentials in header***' in the Auth provider settings is essential.

The problem I see in your screenshots are the scope values (for both Auth Provider & Named credential). According to Salesforce documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_addl_params_scope.htm&type=5),`valid scopes vary depending on the third party; refer to your third-party documentation.` But the values you have used are Salesforce scopes (which are invalid for GTW). Hence, when OAuth flow is initiated (upon Named credential save), GTW doesn't recognize the value as valid scope and refuses to authenticate & authorize. In your case, you should be referring to client app (OAuth client) created in GoToWebinar for valid scope values (see screenshot below for reference)

[image]

The valid scope value for the client app shown in this screen shot is 'identity:scim.me collab:' and you should be specifying this value either in the Auth providers settings or in the Named credential. It's not required to specify in both the places. The scope specified in Named credential will override the default scope specified in the Auth Provider. If scope is not specified in Named credential, then the Auth provider scope will be used.

Also, your apex code is missing the required query parameters (fromTime & toTime) for the REST endpoint. Refer to the official documentation [here](https://goto-developer.logmeininc.com/GoToWebinarV2/#operation/getWebinars). GTW will respond with a HTTP 403 or 401 for incorrect endpoints. With the correct parameters, I was able to get a successful response.

**UPDATE:**
*[This section outlines a specific problem related to access token expiry and how it is handled between Salesforce & GoToWebinar.]*

Enable 'Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header' in the Named Credential settings. This seems to be essential for fetching a new access token after the existing access token expires. *[The screenshots in your question shows this option enabled, but not sure if you had this disabled later]*

[image]

The access and refresh token received from GTW during the initial auth handshake are valid for 60 min and 30 days respectively. After the access token expires, any web request sent to GTW should send an 401 HTTP status response and the caller (in our case SF thru Named Credential & Auth Provider) should be able to fetch a new access token using the refresh token. But, unfortunately that doesn't happen because GTW sends HTTP status codes 403 or 400 for any request that is missing parameter or has incorrect end point URLs. So, a new access token is not fetched and the web request fails.

Although, I couldn't find any official documentation from Salesforce, enabling 'Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header' seems to send additional required parameters in the callout and GTW is able to respond with a new access token.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Arut for your detailed response, would you be able to detail how to refresh the token given the limitations with the response codes? I have created a mock callout to `callout:GoToWebinar/webhooks` which doesn't exist but this returns a 403 error instead of the 401 error expected so my tokens aren't refreshed.

Comment: I believe that the confusing response codes is probably due to a bug in the rest api implementation at GTW (or intentionally done as per their design), with final outcome being the response indicating successful auth but that something went wrong in the request. In your case 403 indicates forbidden request (I would have expected a 404 response) and doesn't say that the authentication was unsuccessful (or access token expired).

Comment: Could you tell me if you are able to send an expired access token in this mock callout scenario and get an incorrect response? As per my knowledge, the initial authentication/ authorization should return a JSON (or whatever content-type is specified in the request) with access token as well as refresh token. So, your code should work fine when the access token actually expires.

Comment: If you are able to actually replicate the scenario, then a custom impl of auth provider may be required (utilizing the GTW endpoints to get refresh token), but I don't think that is required. The TokenEndPoint URL in the Auth Provider settings is the URL to get the refresh token and hence, Salesforce should automatically handle that for you.

Comment: So what I did was simply create that callout that I mentioned above which doesn't exist in anonymous apex to test to see if I could still access the REST endpoint an after a successsful callout (thats how long the tokens last for). My original plan although not best practise was to simply check if I get a 403 response and then make the fake callout and then try again but this doesn't appear to work as expected.

Comment: According the official GTW documentation (in the links mentioned below), access token is valid for 60 min and refresh token is valid for 30 days

https://goto-developer.logmeininc.com/guides/HowTos/03_HOW_accessToken/, 
https://goto-developer.logmeininc.com/guides/HowTos/05_HOW_refreshToken/

In your test scenario, I suggest you test the following sequence in an anonymous code: call out to a valid end point > call out to a mock (non-existent) end point > call out again to a valid end point. 
If you get successful response (HTTP 200) for 1st and 3rd callouts, your access token is valid.

Comment: I believe that that the 403 response you got for the mock callout is just misleading and not to be confused with the expiry of access token. BTW, the end points for getting the access token and refresh token are mentioned in the links in my previous comment.

One other way to test would be add a postman callback URL to the same client app in GTW and observe the tokens received in the response. I don't think GTW would discriminate Salesforce against Postman and the token validity would be the same in both cases.

Comment: Another nugget of information: If GTW or any provider app didn't send the refresh token in the initial auth response, then you might possibly see message similar to the following in the Name credentials (below the Authentication Status field): "The authentication provider didn't provide a refresh token"

Comment: Hi Arut, sorry for the back and fourth... its not really clear to me what your solution is for the refresh token. When I let the token expire (waiting 60+ mins) when trying to reach the same endpoint that worked when the token working, I get a 403 error. My understanding is that if I go to a fake endpoint it would force a new refresh because of a 401 error, but on an endpoint such as `callout:GoToWebinar/webhooks` this still brings back a 403 so I'm not sure how to force a refresh.

Comment: The answer to your problem is to enable 'Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header' in the NamedCredentials settings. This way Salesforce is sending all the required parameters to GTW and able to get a successful response. I'm going to post an update section in my answer with some more details (due to char and formatting limitations in this comments box).

In my earlier comments, I didn't actually mention any solution since you were testing with a mock end point and I felt that it was not really the right way to test. The testing you did as mentioned in your last comments seems correct.

Comment: JFYI: (1) Looking at the API documentation from GTW (https://developer.goto.com/GoToWebinarV2/#section/GoToWebinar-API-Overview), looks like none of the end points respond with 401 status code (there were few end points in the v1 version but none in v2). So, IMO there is no way to force a 401 thru end points with incorrect parameters or incorrect URL. 

(2) Using the end points meant to get the access token and refresh token didn't make sense to me in this case because that defeats the whole purpose of using Named credentials.

Comment: I did not test whether a new refresh token is also fetched after I enabled 'allow merge fields in http header'. If you get a chance to test that or run into problems after refresh token expired, please let me know.

Comment: Allow merge fields was already enabled, although I'm not sure what the purpose of this would be. This would be used when using the token or credentials in the Named Credential as part of my header, but I haven't added anything to that section thats needed for the callout.

Comment: You are right about the fact that this would be needed when using the credential/ token as a part of header in your code and the official Salesforce documentation states so. However, per my observation, this seems to send additional details in the callout request (i.e., you don't have to specify anything additional in your code) and GTW is able to approve the auth and send the correct response.

Comment: I tested the following sequence: Created a new Named Credential and invoked a callout to a valid GTW endpoint > Received a successful HTTP response (200) > Waited for 60 minutes and invoked the same callout code > Received a HTTP 403 response as expected (indicated invalid auth, due to expired access token) > Enabled the merge fields option in Named credentials > Invoked the same callout code again > Received a successful HTTP response (200). So, the conclusion is that enabling this option is sending additional parameters (may be the refresh token) as a part of the auth handshake.

Comment: Have you tested the same sequence as mentioned in my previous comments and still facing the problem? If so, then there is probably some other problem with your code. You could provide some more details in that case.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, why would enabling the merge fields option make this work if you don't actually specify any additional header fields with the merge fields. Nevertheless, this feature was already turned on, and it's not working. I've initially had the callout working, waited 60 minutes for it expire, waited more than a week, returned back to the page and its still saying invalid token (even though the merge field option was enabled)

Comment: Enabling merge field doesn't make sense in this case, but it worked for me. My answers were based on actual test performed from my dev org (by running the same anonymous apex code that you had posted). If its specifically not working for you, it might require some additional troubleshooting in your org? BTW, have you tried in a different org and still facing the same problem?

Comment: I think what's happening is when you edit the Named Credential it forces the NM to re-authenticate. I disabled "allow merge fields in HTTP Body" and the callouts worked again, I'm gonna wait 60 minutes and see if its still working (I suspect not). If you go back to your org where you made that change is it still working?

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I had meant by asking you to update the "allow merge fields in HTTP body". I didn't realize you were working with an already enabled option. The authentication will work if you try after 60 min. One thing I didn't check though was what happens after 30 days when the refresh token itself expires. I suspect it should work fine though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot test it now in my org because I was working with a trial subscription of GTW which expired and it's  giving me a 403 now (because of either incorrect endpoint URL or invalid subscription). I would have a create a new trial subscription and try it out.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, but I think by toggling the merge fields solution won't work. This would mean I need to toggle this option every time the token expires (and returns a 403) which isn't a workable solution to me as that would be every 60 minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111873/discussion-between-arut-and-deployment-failure).