# Custom Merge Field Named Credential Apex

Tags: apex, oauth2, namedcredentials, auth-provider, auth

I am integrating with [GoToWebinar](https://developer.goto.com/guides/HowTos/03_HOW_accessToken/) using a Named Credential to make Apex Callouts. While the Authentication piece is working well, during the Callback to get the access token, there are some additional attributes:

```
{
 "access_token": "eyJraWQiOiJvYXV0aHYyLmxt666...",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "refresh_token": "eyJraWQiOiJvYXV0aHYyLmxt999...",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "account_key": "9999982253621659654",
  "account_type": "",
  "email": "mister.jones@fakemail.com",
  "firstName": "Moon",
  "lastName": "Beam",
  "organizer_key": "8439885694023999999",
  "version": "3"
 }
```

That I would like to use a Merge field in my callout (i.e. `{!$Credential.organizer_key}`). Is this possible or do I have to manually perform all of this in Apex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Named Credential authentication with GoToWebinar (OAuth2)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313841/named-credential-authentication-with-gotowebinar-oauth2)

Comment: No, it doesn't talk about how to get the `organizer_key` from the merge field

Comment: That JSON is a response from GoTo. Named Credentials + merge is for requests. For parsing the response, have a look at [Deserializing JSON in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57459/how-to-deserialize-a-json-string-to-apex)

Comment: I understand that is it coming back from GoTo. What I am trying to understand is if Salesforce is capturing the entire JSON during the Named Credential callback, and then I can use the other attributes (i.e `organizer_key`) as a merge variable for future callouts

Comment: Only the access token from the response is available as a merge field for callouts.